# Calculating the distance between two coordinate points

Tags: javascript, html

The following is my code that calculates the distance between two coordinate points. However, when I run this code, I cannot press the button indicated on the screen. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Distance Calculator</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateDistance(xValue1, yValue1, xValue2, yValue2)
            {
                xValue1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x1').value);       
                yValue1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y1').value);
                xValue2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x2').value);       
                yValue2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y2').value);

                var point1;
                var point2;
                var distance;

                point1 = Math.pow(xValue1 - xValue2, 2);
                point2 = Math.pow(yValue1 - yValue2, 2);

                distance = Math.sqrt(point1 + point2);

                document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 
                'The distance between ' + xValue1 + ',' + yValue1 + 'and ' + xValue2 + ',' + yValue2 + 'is ' + distance;>
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Distance Calculator</h1>
            <p>
                Coordinate 1: <input type="text id=x1" size=12> , <input type="text id=y1" size=12><br>
                Coordinate 2: <input type="text id=x2" size=12> , <input type="text id=y2" size=12><br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Calculate Distance"
                onclick="calculateDistance();">
            </p>
        <hr>
        <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `type="text id=x1"` should be `type="text" id="x1"`

Comment: You should really learn how to use the console to fix simple errors.

Comment: As well as the `type="text id=x1"` error, there's a spurious `>` at the end of  the line beginning with `'The distance between '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is broken. The `input`s had mismatched `"` between the `type` and `id`. You're JavaScript function also required 4 parameters, which were never set.

I removed the parameters from the function and added `var`s to the variable xValue1 and so one. Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10nbqweL/

Answer (score 3):

There are many errors in this,

1. Coordinate 1: `<input type="text id=x1" size=12>`

   should be

   Coordinate 1: `<input type="text" id="x1" size=12>`
2. Your function has 4 parameters, but never uses them, whilst this will work, it's poor practice, change them to vars declared inside your function.

   ```
      function calculateDistance()
       {
           var xValue1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x1').value);       
           var yValue1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y1').value);
           var xValue2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x2').value);       
           var yValue2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y2').value);
   ```
3. You also have `;>}` at the end of

   `document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
          'The distance between ' + xValue1 + ',' + yValue1 + 'and ' + xValue2 + ',' + yValue2 + 'is ' + distance;>}` The > is unnecessary.

https://jsfiddle.net/d56ph9yr/

Answer (score -1):

`calculateDistance` takes four arguments, you supply none.

You also don't use them; you get them via `getElementById` as the first action of the function.  Declare them as variables and remove them as arguments and you should be golden.

*Edit: You should be seeing a javascript error in your developer console when you try to click the button, given the lack of a definition matching the invocation.*

Comment: That may be true but it's not the problem.